# Limitations of Running Multiple Instances of MS SQL EXPRESS

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I plan on installing Multiple Instances of MS SQL EXPRESS on my Development Server.

I am hoping this will let me get around the [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) of SQL EXPRESS:

- 1 GB of RAM,
- 1 CPU
- Database size max 4 GB

[I understand and wish that I could afford a full licence version of SQL Server.]

So, would this work? Would each instance have their own independent limitations?

Comment: How exactly do you create another instance on the same machine? I couldn't find the way...

Comment: the link seems broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an MSDN subscription then you can install the Development version and I don't believe that has any restrictions...of course it's for development purposes only.

You can purchase SQL Server Developer Edition from Microsoft at this link...it's $50

http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/SQL-Server-2008-Developer-Edition/product/C5EA00C9

---

As of 2016 (?) SQL Server Developer Edition is **Free**, downloadable at [microsoft.com/sqlserver](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799009).

Comment: Aye this would be nice! Seriously considering applying for bizspark

Comment: Oh ok, wasn't aware of this developer edition.  Thanks for the tip.  I will check it out

Comment: Interesting... They are now out of Stock!  I wonder if this is due to this tread? LOL

Comment: I ended up joining BizSpark.  Great initiative by MS!
Thanks for supporting startups!

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is yes.

All instances will have their own independent limitations.

Problems that you will face are:

- Obvious performance issue.
- OS will decide which processor they will use, and there is a good chance 
   that they will all use the same one. You need to try that.
- Servers need to listen on separate ports.
- Separate master databases, separate collations, no easy cross-database queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get this done, every instance will behave and run under the same limitations. Also, you will need to configure the ports since each instance will attempt to listen on the same port.

Comment: Each instance will have a unique name Box\Instance1 Box\Instance2 etc
Will they still need to be assigned to different ports?

Comment: Default instances will attempt to listen on TCP/1433. However, you can only have one default instance installed on a server. Named instances, by default, will use dynamic port assignment. You can set the ports statically, but that's not the default.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a development server, I would second the recommendation to go with a copy of Developer Edition. Developer Edition is a specially licensed version of Enterprise Edition which allows you to run it on operating system versions where Enterprise Edition would not normally be allowed to run. The catch is it an only be used for development. At $50, it's well worth the cost.

The problem with running multiple instances is you face the prospect of resource contention for CPU and memory between the instances. You can throttle the memory for each instance and things of that sort, but if you have the option, going with the Developer Edition instance will be simpler and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, by design, an SQL Server will take as much memory as it can (the larger its cache, the better its performance will be) and, as such, running 4 SQL Servers will simply fight for your RAM (1gig is nowhere near enough.)

That said, the maximum database size is 4 gig, but, unless you’re dealing with images, you'll be surprised just how much that is.

We used SQL Express and it was fine for what we were using it for (10 user client/server application), plenty of SQL and plenty of queries every second.  I would recommend using the express version and looking into a better one in the future.

FYI: Microsoft Small Business Server (SBS) comes with a workstation version of SQL Server plus Exchange which means it is EXTREMELY cost effective for a starting business.

Also, if your idea is good, you should look at the Microsoft programs for new companies (It used to be called empower, it has a new name now...). They are really really good in terms of software, especially server software.

Comment: He said he was looking for a development server option not a production server option but SBS is a very good choice provided you can live with it being your domain controller too.

Comment: FWIW, with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express the data limitation was bumped to 10GB, and that doesn't include FILESTREAM space. So, if you're storing images in a FILESTREAM instead of as BLOBs in a table then you can eek out even more from an express install.